# Flutter place TextButton as far as possible

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want a Skip Tutorial TextButton in the very top right corner, how do I do this?

```
ListView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 241, top: 20),
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RootWidget()),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Überspringen",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  "Welcome",
                  style: themeData.textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
```

.... and more code, but not important for this question. May you help me there? :D
Like it is in this screenshot, but when I use a different Mediaquery it's positioned wrong. So I need it depend on the mediaquery.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Column(children: [
      SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const RootWidget()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text(
                  "Überspringen",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15), children: [
          Text(
            "Welcome",
          ),
        ]),
      )
    ]);
```

Comment: thanks :D Didn't know that there is a "end" ;) !